# Can someone give an example of a boolean expression that is shorter than its minimal DNF form?

Tags: optimization, boolean-expression

Generally minimal DNF shortens a boolean expression but I believe there are cases where it lengthens, but I can't easily find one.

Answer (score 1):

From the point of the expression length I would compare only expressions normalized to their minimal CNF or minimal DNF suspecting, that every expression can be lengthen by *appending* the right neutral element or it's arbitrary equivalent without changing it's logical value.

**Simple examples** of a shorter boolean expression in minimal CNF and *longer* minimal DNF would be these shown in **minimal CNF** first:

```
(a ∨ b) ∧ c

(u ∨ v ∨ w) ∧ z
```

because the conjunction as the root binary relation is great for CNF, but it forces you to *multiply* the insides of the brackets with literal c (z respectively) to change it to minimal DNF.

Here is the equivalent boolean expression shown in it's **minimal DNF**:

```
(a ∧ c) ∨ (b ∧ c)

(u ∧ z) ∨ (v ∧ z) ∨ (w ∧ z)
```

You can also find and compare this boolean expression's minimal DNF and minimal CNF by using K-maps as shown in the next picture (generated by latex). This way is also visible which of these would be easier to mark out.

[image: K-maps of the two examples' minimal forms]